# how to hide search box in windows 10 taskbar

Tags: taskbar, windows-10-preview

Today i installed windows 10 technical preview in my machine,once started i was able to view the search box at task bar ,is it there any way to disable/hide search box in windows 10,its bit annoying while using it .how can i disable/hide the search box in windows 10 task bar?

any registry/group policy setting to hide the search box in windows 10?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a rightclick on the taskbar, and under `search`, select `disabled`.

[image]

You can still invoke search via <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem obvious, however it took me a while to realize - if you can't see the Search in the Taskbar menu - look for Cortana instead.
[image]